# CGI script skipping source command

Tags: bash, shell, cgi

I am trying to write a cgi that will write an html file so I don't have to run the script every time I want to see the information.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<HTML>"
echo "<head><title>Status</title></head>"
echo "<body>"
./auto.sh > ../secure/status.html
echo "Redirecting..."
echo "<script language="javascript">window.location.href="../secure/status.html";</script>"
echo "</body></HTML>"
```

However, when I direct the browser to the page, the page source shows this, but it didn't run the redirect command, and doesn't even redirect...

```
<HTML>
<head><title>Status</title></head>
<body>
Redirecting...
<script language=javascript>window.location.href = ../secure/status.html;</script>
</body></HTML>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!!

Edit:  This is my auto.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "<HTML><head><title>Status</title></head><body><pre>"
echo "$(date)"
echo ""
FAILED=$(sudo cat /var/log/secure | grep "$(date +"%b %d")" | grep "sshd" | grep "Failed")
ACCEPTED=$(sudo cat /var/log/secure | grep "$(date +"%b %d")" | grep "sshd" | grep "Accepted")
SPEED=$(python /script/speedtest-cli --server 4128 | grep "Download:\|Upload:")
BAN=$(sudo cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" | grep "Ban")

echo "##########FAILED##########"
echo "$FAILED"
echo ""
echo "##########ACCEPTED##########"
echo "$ACCEPTED"
echo ""
echo "##########BANNED##########"
echo "$BAN"
echo ""
echo "##########SPEED##########"
echo "$SPEED"
echo ""
echo "##########STORAGE##########"
echo "$(df -h)"
echo ""
echo "##########MEMORY##########"
echo "$(free -m)"
echo ""
echo "<a href="../cgi-bin/status.cgi">Refresh</a>"
echo "</pre></body></HTML>"
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to `echo "$(free -m)"`, just do `free -m`. 2) the auto script already prints out the header,  so  the cgi script doesn't have to.

Comment: When the cgi script runs, I don't want to see the auto.sh, I just want it to be saved to an html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the redirect code (including the script tag) in the `<head>` of the document.

I would also amend the bash script so that it puts the destination in double-quotes (rendering the output as) `window.location.href="../secure/status.html";`
Single-quotes are ok too. It just seems your bash script usage of quotes is not quoting the items as you are trying to do.

Lastly, if you want the user actually seeing the words "Redirecting" you should invoke some kind of time delay in the javascript code.

Try :
`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='../secure/status.html';</script>"`

I took a small part of your auto.sh file and then redirected its output to a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# subset of your file auto.sh

echo "<HTML><head><title>Status</title></head><body><pre>"
echo "$(date)"
echo ""
FAILED="Failed"
ACCEPTED="Accepted"
BAN="Ban"
echo "##########FAILED##########"
echo "$FAILED"
echo ""
echo "##########ACCEPTED##########"
echo "$ACCEPTED"
echo ""
echo "##########BANNED##########"
echo "$BAN"
echo ""
echo '<a href="../cgi-bin/status.cgi">Refresh</a>'
echo "</pre></body></HTML>"
```

Note the single-quotes in the href line.

Then, I executed this on the Command Line:
`sh auto.sh > status.html`

Lastly, I executed `cat status.html` and got this...

```
<HTML><head><title>Status</title></head><body><pre>
Thu, Oct 22, 2015  3:09:43 PM

##########FAILED##########
Failed

##########ACCEPTED##########
Accepted

##########BANNED##########
Ban

<a href="../cgi-bin/status.cgi">Refresh</a>
</pre></body></HTML>
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: In my actual script I have it in double quotes, the page source just doesn't show them.  I moved my redirect line into the head, but it didn't do anything...

Comment: I tried single quotes, and it redirects now!!  Thanks.  It still doesn't write to status.html tho...

Comment: Based on your Original Post, I read a manual page as I never heard of the `tee` command before.   In the reference page http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm it does indicate that `tee` writes to a file.  Since I've not yet used tee, I've always written files by echoing some text and redirecting using the single greater-than sign `>` for overwrite, or the double-greater than `>>` to append.

Comment: Is it possible that you're trying to add text to a file at same time (or close to it) that the output of `auto.sh` is being redirected to same file?  Perhaps information is getting over-written unintentionally.

Comment: Hrm, I don't know if I follow you...  I think there is only one thing connected to the html file?  Is there a better way to go about this?  I was just trying to send the output to a file so I didn't have to run the script every time I looked at it.

Comment: I'd suggest having one script that has no commands to redirect output but simply just produces the text-based output you need. Then have a command or other that basically does the equivalent of `sh outputProducer.sh > "../secure/status.html"`

Comment: I've revised my original answer to include some essential parts of auto.sh and the command used to generate output and redirect the output to a file called `status.html`.  Hope it helps.